# Use function on each row based on whether values are greater than another value in that row

Tags: r

I am trying to get a sum of multiple columns (but not all) in a dataframe, using R. The catch is that I only want to sum the values that are greater than the median value of that row's values, AND ignore zeros.

Here is an example showing two rows of `data` which has say, 20 columns, of which 6 (columns x1:x6) have the values I want to consider for the sum:

```
x1  x2  x3  x4  x5 x6
4   4   5   0   0  2
2   3   0   1   5  0
```

Ignoring zeros, the median is 4 for the first row and 2.5 for the second. So I want to sum the remaining numbers that are > 4 in the first row, and > 2.5 in the second, and place these numbers in a new column.

There are many rows of data. I have already placed the median value (I just used excel to get this) in another column, which I will call `data$med_no_zero` so this can be used instead of having to calculate that value in the R code.

I have played around with if/then statements, the apply function, and some other things, but I'm pretty new to R and coding so I keep getting stuck. I've searched online extensively but haven't found an example that seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` on rows (`MARGIN = 1`) to run the required function

```
apply(X = df, MARGIN = 1, function(x)
    sum(x[x > median(replace(x, x==0, NA), na.rm = TRUE)], na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] 5 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative that uses `rowSums` to calculate the sums and uses a trick with NA and exponentiation to turn the zeros into NA so that they can be removed in the median calculation.

```
rowSums(dat * (dat > apply(dat * NA^!dat, 1, median, na.rm=TRUE)))
[1] 5 8
```

`apply(dat * NA^!dat, 1, median, na.rm=TRUE)` calculates the median values of each row, dropping values that are 0 by converting these values to NA with `dat * NA^!dat` and then using `na.rm` argument in `median`.

Then `dat > apply(dat * NA^!dat, 1, median, na.rm=TRUE)` returns a logical matrix where the entry is TRUE if the cell value in dat is greater then the median of the row (this comparison is accomplished through recycling).

Finally, we get multiply dat to this matrix to get the values of dat that are greater than the modified median and 0s elsewhere. The result is fed to `rowSums` which calculates the total of each row.

**data**

```
dat <-
structure(list(x1 = c(4L, 2L), x2 = c(4L, 3L), x3 = c(5L, 0L), 
    x4 = 0:1, x5 = c(0L, 5L), x6 = c(2L, 0L)), .Names = c("x1", 
"x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. It's great to see other ways of doing this and I appreciate your explanation of the steps!